# Join filter between more than two tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

So, I have a scenario where I have an article that I want to be filtered based on two other articles in the publication.  If I were to write this as T-SQL, it'd be:

```
select t3.*
from t3
inner join t2
   on t3.t2_id = t2.t2_id
inner join t1
   on t3.t1_id = t1.t1_id
```

Looking at `sp_addmergefilter`, it accepts a parameter called `@join_articlename` which implies that you can only join to one table at a time.  Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question may be better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: You might be right.  However, I'll note the from the BOL article on sp_addmergefilter: "Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed database role can execute sp_addmergefilter.".  Seems like a sysadmin task to me.

Comment: @BenThul A note saying you need dbo to execute a certain stored procedure does not a sysadmin question make.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178584.aspx: `Only members of the sysadmin fixed server role or db_owner fixed database role can execute sp_addmergefilter.`  That doesn't mean that you need a sysadmin to build your query, it means your database privileges need to be configured correctly for the procedure to run once you've built it.  Please review the [faq] for guidelines on what's on topic here.

Comment: Then vote to move it if you think it's off-topic for this site.